# Utilização correta de Mutators do Laravel 5.1. É possível utilizar nesta maneira descrita abaixo?

Tags: laravel

Olá, estou utilizando Laravel 5.1 no momento e me apareceu uma dúvida. Tenho um grid que mostra valores de um determinado CRUD e nela busco através de Tabela::all(), que me retorna algo como:

```
array:5 [▼  
"primary_key_id" => 1,
"foreing_key_id" => 5,
"name" => "testes",
"created_at" => "2015-10-05 21:25:27",
"updated_at" => "2015-10-05 21:25:27"
```

Gostaria de adicionar neste objeto o nome da foreing_key, ou seja:

```
array:6 [▼  
"primary_key_id" => 1,
"foreing_key_id" => 5,
"name" => "testes",
"created_at" => "2015-10-05 21:25:27",
"updated_at" => "2015-10-05 21:25:27",
**"foreing_key_name = "Teste"**
```

Tentei utilizar o conceito de Mutators do Laravel e através do print que fiz dentro do método de fato ele adicionou o que eu queria, porém não consigo acessar na view e nem lugar nenhum, e não aparece dentro do objeto dentro do controller. Estou utilizando correto o conceito do Mutators ou vou ter que fazer um JOIN para resolver isso?

Exemplo do mutator:

```
getForeingKeyIdAttribute($value){
       $this->attributes['foreing_key_name'] = TableDaForeinkey::where('name','=', $value )->first()->name;
   }
```

Comment: Publique seus models se possível. Isso ajuda a reproduzir sua dúvida.

Comment: Para fazer outra consulta não acho uma boa ideia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o `with` para assim trazer o model relacionado:

```
Tabela::with('relationMethod')->get();
```

app/Tabela.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class tabela extends Model
{
    public function relationMethod()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\RelationModel');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Você deve criar um `$appends` no seu `model (Eloquent)` seguindo um exemplo dado pelo site Laravel.

Crie um item dentro do seu model dessa forma

```
protected $appends = ['is_admin'];
```

Agora crie o seu Acessor

```
public function getIsAdminAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['admin'] == 'yes';
}
```

Agora você vai receber um campo a mais no seu `JSON` ou `Array` de forma mais transparente e sem alterar os dados principais do seu `model`.

Confira se também colocou o `$fillable` que define quais elementos são referente aos campos da tabela para não ter problema na hora de gravar, alterar e excluir itens desse model

```
protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email'];
```

Para tirar a maior dúvida veja o link do próprio Laravel: [#Mass Assignment](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Comment: Isso mesmo. Estava faltando no meu caso apenas o  $appends. Assim eu consegui acessa-lo na view.